# Unable to understand proof of the Interior Extremum Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying from the book "Introduction to Real Analysis" by Bartle and Sherbert. In the proof of the Interior Extremum Theorem, to prove that $f'(c) = 0$, they rule out the other two possibilities by deriving contradictions whenever $f'(c) > 0$ and $f'(c) < 0$. To do so, they use the fact (theorem 4.2.9) that if the limit of a function $f$ is strictly positive at a cluster point, say $c$, then there exists a $\delta$-neighbourhood of $c$ such that $f(x) > 0$ in that neighbourhood. Assuming for a contradiction that,

$f'(c) > 0$ which means : $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} \dfrac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c} > 0$

Since this limit is strictly positive, there must exist a $V_{\delta}(c)$ such that the difference quotient is strictly positive. Then they make the statement that if $x \in V_{\delta}(c)$ and $x > c$... we get a contradiction. At this point why do we disregard the possibility that $x < c$? In order for a quotient to be positive both numerator and denominator must have the same sign. Since $f(x) < f(c)$ because $f(c)$ is a local maximum, the denominator must also be less than $0$,thus forcing $x < c$.

Doesn't the contradiction in fact show that we may not assume $x>c$? A similar case holds when $f'(c) < 0$ where, we need opposite signs forcing $x > c$. Having forced this condition on $x$, should we not proceed further (I don't know how) to somehow show that even with this restriction on $x$, we still get some contradiction, and thus rule out $f'(c) > 0$? What mistake am I making, or what fact am I overlooking?

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The other cases are just not of interest to get the contradiction, they still exist. Assume 
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}>ε\text{ for }|x-c|<δ
$$
Then for $x>c$ we get $x-c>0$ so that the inequality can be transformed as
$$
f(x)-f(c)>ε·(x-c)>0
$$
which gives the contradiction.

On the other hand, $x<c$ results in $(x-c)<0$ and thus the transformed inequality
$$
f(x)-f(c)<ε·(x-c)<0
$$
which is not a contradiction at all since $f(c)$ was assumed to be the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Neighbourhoods in the usual topology of the real numbers extend on both sides of the point of which they are a neighbourhood.

The neighbourhood $V_\delta$ must contain elements $x$ that are greater than $c$ and these elements lead to a contradiction.

So the contradiction follows from the established fact that such a neighbourhood has at least one $x>c.$ The contradiction does not prove that (any) $x$ is less than $c,$ but that no such neighbourhood exists.